# Java input date from Scanner in one line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to read date from a user to pass to GregorianCalendar variable. Currently I have an awkward setup, where it reads line by line. Can you help with a solution that collects input in one line? I found SimpleDateFormat class, but I cannot find a good fit for this specific purpose.

```
    Scanner time = new Scanner(System.in)

    System.out.println("Type year: ");int y =time.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type month: ");int m =time.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type day: ");int d = time.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type hour: ");int h = time.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type minute: ");int mm = time.nextInt();

    GregorianCalendar data = new GregorianCalendar(y,m,d,h,mm);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you read in a line of text, with a specific format, then use `DateFormat` to parse it. For example:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm",
                                         Locale.US);
System.out.println("Enter date and time in the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm");
System.out.println("For example, it is now " + format.format(new Date()));
Date date = null;
while (date == null) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    try {
        date = format.parse(line);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that's not valid. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

If you can, use the Java 8 `java.time` classes, or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) - with the same basic idea, but using the classes from those APIs. Both are *much* better than using `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: Hi Jon, I understand there are likely some better solutions. Meanwhile I'm still learning, I checked your solution and it seems "date" is not the format accepted as constructor in GregorianCalendar (and I already use GregorianCalendar). So if there is some other solution  that does (and is not too difficult) I will appreciate it. Thank you by the way.

Comment: @Turo: You would call set time on the calendar after constructing it.

Comment: what do you mean by set time?

Comment: ok, got it:) setTime method of GregorianCalendar . will try it, thank you

Comment: @Turo The format suggested in the Answer is the standard one, defined by [`ISO 8601`](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). That sensible format is becoming more common in business and industry, and is usually specified in modern internet and information protocols. That format is used by both Joda-Time and java.time as a default for borne generating and parsing string representations of date-time values.